# node is unable to find module (even though it's installed)

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm writing a [CLI utility](https://github.com/nealrs/cpupdate/tree/exp) using the [zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) headless browser package.

Originally, I installed the dependencies locally as I needed them `npm install zombie foo bar` and the script worked just fine.

But since writing the package.json everytime I try to install or run the script locally, I get this module error:

```text
$ node index.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'zombie'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/neal/Downloads/cpupdate-exp/index.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

This happens no matter how I try installing the packages. Which makes no sense. I can see them in my local `node_modules` directory & everything.

**So I guess my question is, is my package.json wrong or did I mess up my node installation somewhere along the way?**

BTW, I also tried installing zombie fresh in a separate directory & running a really simple script (below), but I get the same `Cannot find module` error.

```
var browser = require("zombie");
var assert = require("assert");

b = new browser();
b.visit("http://nealshyam.com/", function () {
 assert.ok(browser.success);
 console.log(browser.text("title"));
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "author": "Neal Shyam",
  "name": "cpupdate",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "Update your ChallengePost Portfolio with node.js",
  "homepage": "http://challengepost.com/software/cpupdate",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs":{
    "url":"https://github.com/nealrs/cpupdate/issues",
    "email":"neal@challengepost.com"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:nealrs/cpupdate.git"
  },
  "bin": "./index.js",
  "keywords": [
    "ChallengePost",
    "update",
    "portfolio"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "zombie": "assaf/zombie",
    "assert": "defunctzombie/commonjs-assert",
    "open": "pwnall/node-open",
    "colors": "Marak/colors.js",
    "nomnom": "harthur/nomnom"
  },
  "preferGlobal": "true"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably is a bug in the `zombie` package that you should report upstream: https://github.com/assaf/zombie

The reason for this error is that after `npm install` some necessary files are missing in the `node_modules/zombie` folder. Namely: The `lib` folder is missing in there. The `package.json` of `zombie` specifies the entrypoint as follows:

```
"main": "lib/zombie",
```

Changing into `node_modules/zombie` and running `npm install` in there fixes the issue, the build process properly creates the `lib` folder.

Comment: Whew - ok, so I'm not crazy. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution by TimWolla did not work for me. What worked for me was to just go to another folder and do `npm install zombie@2.5.1` , after that went back to my project removed the node_modules folder and did `npm install` again for the project. The lib folder was created and zombie worked.